# The phase of the eigenvalue for the LCU method and randomized product formula

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, quantum-phase-estimation, random-quantum-circuit

If we implement the linear combination of unitary(LCU), $\tilde{U}=\sum_i p_i U_i$, onto its eigenstate, $|\psi \rangle$, we can express its eigenvalue as $re^{i\theta}$, where $\sum_ip_i=1$, $0\leq p_i \leq 1$, and $r,\theta\in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{equation} \tilde{U}|\psi\rangle=re^{i\theta}|\psi\rangle. \end{equation}

There is another kind of Hamiltonian simulation method, called randomized product formula. For example, the qDRIFT method is developed by Earl Campbell https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.08017.pdf, or the randomized product formula is developed by Andrew M. Childs et.al https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08385.pdf. We can implement the operation on the density operator $\rho$,
\begin{equation}  \sum_ip_iU_i\rho U_i^{\dagger}.    \end{equation}

My question is:
can I say that when we use the randomized product formula as the Hamiltonian simulation method in quantum phase estimation, the phase that we obtain is also $\theta$?